# Cassandra ASYN WRITE

Tags: asynchronous, cassandra, insert-update

In Cassandra, I need a CL that assures that I can do 100% ASYNC WRITEs. So, Ideally, the coordinator node should journal the data and return SUCCESS.

Looking at the Docs, there is no CL level that does this. The doc on ANY says that it has to write into at least one node.

So, is there a way of doing ASYNC write in Cassandra?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you continue in that doc

> A write must be written to at least one node. *If all replica nodes
>   for the given row key are down, the write can still succeed after a
>   hinted handoff has been written.* If all replica nodes are down at
>   write time, an ANY write is not readable until the replica nodes for
>   that row have recovered.  Provides low latency and a guarantee that a
>   write never fails. Delivers the lowest consistency and highest
>   availability compared to other levels.

So ANY is what you are looking for (Coordinator only write or hint logging)

Comment: Not really if any replica is up. At least this is how I understand this documentation. If all replicas are down, yes, hint logging will happen, but if any replica is up, it will write to at least one replica before return SUCCESS. Now, that replica might not even be local, right?

Comment: If any replica is up, token aware routing will send the query from the driver to the machine which is a replica. So either you do a real write, or you do a hint write. So yeah this is basically as fast as you can ever be.

Comment: Yes, I wish, the coordinator would have done the "hint write" and returned success for all cases. Now, you are much faster if all the replicas are down and otherwise much slower because of the remote-write!

Comment: If any replica is up and the query is routed to a replica (by the driver on your client not in the cluster) and it will write to the commit log and to memory (but only block for memory)

If no replicas are up it writes to the commit log and the hints (which is a table in c* prior to C* 3.0 and on disk after that.) I'm not sure why you think that's faster?

Comment: If the replica is remote and far away, reaching this replica will be much more expensive than writing into coordinator's local disk, right?

Comment: From the client? The client is close to some nodes but far from others? I could only understand that if you data belongs in a different datacenter, but you should probably just connect to the correct datacenter in the first place. 

Here is an example where I could imagine this being the case: The client is sitting near your queue or other source on US-EAST but you are actually writing to replicas in US-WEST, But you happen to still have nodes in US-EAST but they aren't replicas?

If you had this I would just blacklist all nodes in US-WEST and use any.

Comment: Well what I really would do is change my replication to be in the same datacenter as the client...

Comment: First of all, thanks for these feedbacks. This data does not have a "locality". It is a URL of some content that we serve. A popular URL could be served from many places in the world. So, the data is not data-center specific. Setting RF to same data center would make the data to be duplicated in every data-center. This particular use case is EXTREMELY latency sensitive as the code reaching to Cassandra is living inside Nginx and is supposed to save some info into Cassandra while serving the content. So, ideally, it has to be a completely ASYNC write!

Comment: Perhaps what you actually want to do is write to a Queue and then have the queue drain to C*. This would allow you the least amount of latency possible on write.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, I have decided to write into SYSLOG!